# Show that $t_n$ of $\textrm{GCD}(a,b)$ is $O(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Can someone help me show that $t_n$ is $O(n)$.

I have using Euclids algorithm and $t_n$ is the worst-case steps to solve $\textrm{GCD}(a,b)$ when $n \geq a \geq b > 0$.

Comment: What is $t_n$ here?

Comment: it says that $t_n$ largest (worst-case) number of  steps that we have to use to solve GCD(a,b) when $n ≥ a ≥ b >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just write the algorithm here:

$a_0:=a$

$b_0:=b$

$r:=b$

While($r \neq 0$)

$r:=$ Remainder of euclidean division of $a$ by $b$

$a_0:=b_0$

$b_0:=r$

endWhile

gcd:=$a_0$

At each step $r$ will get smaller by at least one, since the new $r$ is strictly smaller then the old one. If we start with $r:=b \leq n$, we can have therefore at most $n$ steps before we get to our condition $r=0$. Hence $t_n \leq n$, therefore in particular $t_n= O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some my thought, maybe helpful. The worst case is when $a=n$ and $b=1$ if $1$ doesn't divide all the $k<=n$. But this is wrong, hence I think $b=2$ is a proper choice(and also the worst choice), and I denote $n$ in binary system, the worst case for $n$ is $n=(\underbrace{11\dots 1}_{m})_{(2)}$, and then $t_n= m=\log_{2}n$.